# ¿Como obtener la velocidad del procesador y el resto de la informacion de hardware?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ya utilice la clase build pero no me da la información que necesito, al igual que la clase HardwarePropertiesManager.
Me da una que otra información que si me sirvió como la versión del SO, etc pero lo primordial que necesito es la cantidad de memoria RAM e información del procesador y GPU.
Espero verme explicado bien, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Duany, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, aporta más datos e información, que es lo que has tratado?, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

ve a cmd y escribe

Toda la Información sobre tu CPU

```
WMIC /Output:STDOUT CPU get /all /format:LIST
```

Toda la Información sobre tu CDROM

```
WMIC /Output:STDOUT CDROM get /all /format:LIST
```

Toda la Información sobre REDES

```
WMIC /Output:STDOUT NICCONFIG get /all /format:LIST
```

Toda la Información sobre tu sistema

```
WMIC /Output:STDOUT COMPUTERSYSTEM get /all /format:LIST
```

Toda la Información sobre tus discos

```
WMIC /Output:STDOUT DISKDRIVE get /all /format:LIST
```

Toda la Información sobre discos logicos

```
WMIC /Output:STDOUT LOGICALDISK get /all /format:LIST
```

Toda la Información sobre tu memoria

```
WMIC /Output:STDOUT MEMPHYSICAL get /all /format:LIST
```

Toda la Información sobre los servicios

```
WMIC /Output:STDOUT SERVICE get /all /format:LIST
```

Toda la Información sobre los procesos

```
WMIC /Output:STDOUT PROCESS get /all /format:LIST
```

Toda la Información sobre los programas en el inicio de Windows

```
WMIC /Output:STDOUT STARTUP get /all /format:LIST
```

Toda la Información sobre los dispositivos en tu motherboard

```
WMIC /Output:STDOUT ONBOARDDEVICE get /all /format:LIST
```

Toda la Información sobre errores del sistema operativo

```
WMIC /Output:STDOUT RECOVEROS get /all /format:LIST
```

Comment: Creo que lo que el necesita es saber la información de hardware del móvil donde se instale la app, por consola se puede hacer pero necesita código que lo haga por si solo su app

Comment: Bienvenido, gracias por contribuir pero debes mejorar tu respuesta, revisa por favor el documento [answer]. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!